# Versioning an app retrospectively

Tags: git, version-control, version

I've recently started working on an app project that's a couple of years old.  They want to start doing code releases and versioning just to record all the changes after each iteration.

Is there an efficient way to figure out what the current version should be?  There are approx 5000 commits in the current master that I'm guessing I'll just have to rake through.

Comment: Not clear to me what you're asking.  How are there 5000 commits if you're just getting ready to start versioning?  How do you define what "the current version should be"?

Comment: I'm saying the project has been going on for years and they have not been tracking the version with each incremental change.. to the point where they are now (5000 commits), and version ???.  I'm asking is there an efficient way in git to figure out a version number for the current position they are at, without raking through 5000 commits looking for patches, minor and major commits?

Comment: ?  So why not declare a current version number and track version numbers going forward. It doesn't really matter what you declare the current version to be. Someone will have a marketing reason they don't want it to be 1.0.0, but other than that it would only matter as a way to differentiate from previous version numbers that don't exist. (You could go through all of history and determine a version for every commit... but it's going to take a lot of work, and where's the bang for the buck considering that *nobody in the installed base will know about these new numbers anyway*?)

Comment: Right - it doesn't make too much sense to do it if it's going to be tons of work, I was just all for doing things "properly", but you're right in that it probably doesn't matter.  I guess calling the current version 1.0 would be a good starting point since it's the only major version we've had.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: @s89_ You can add answer for the way you are using, and mark the answer later. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT - thanks for the tip / reminder, I added some info below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out we had been tracking versions of our software, but we were just incrementing each release by 0.0.1 every time.  I'll write out below what my plan is, in case it helps someone.

As another poster suggested, we are just going to use the current figure we are at, 1.4.16, as a starting point - because everything before that is fairly meaningless.

I'll be trying to introduce semantic versioning (detailed here - https://semver.org/) which seems to be the industry standard, and summarised briefly..

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> 1. MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes
> 2. MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner
> 3. and PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

On top of that, I'll be using `git tag` (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) to tag commits at every release, and create releases on Github, which has some handy features to store our release notes.  The good thing about tagging is that you CAN tag commits retrospectively - so if you wanted to, you could tag previous commits as v1.x.x. however far back you wanted to go.